# How to display datepicker in UTC format instead of local time using bootstrap-datetime-picker-for-rails gem

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, datepicker, rubygems, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am using bootstrap-datetime-picker-for-rails gem in my ruby on rails application. It shows local time for user to select the date & time but I need user to select UTC time and save in DB as UTC time.Is there a way to make the bootstrap-datetime-picker-for-rails to appear in UTC format.

Gemfile:

gem 'bootstrap-datetime-picker-for-rails', '~> 0.0.4'

JS file

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', ->
    $(".form_datetime").datetimepicker({
        format: "yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii",
        autoclose: true,
        todayBtn: true,
        pickerPosition: "bottom-left"
    });
    )
```

form.html.erb

```
 <div class="field">
      <%= form.label :raised_at %>
      <%= form.text_field :raised_at, value: abc.raised_at.try(:strftime,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"), class: 'form_datetime', autocomplete: 'off',readonly: true %>
    </div>
```

Updated code:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', () => {
    $(".form_datetime").datetimepicker({
        format: "yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii Z",
        autoclose: true,
        todayBtn: true,
        pickerPosition: "bottom-left"
        // defaultDate:  new Date(Date.setTime(Date.getTime() + (Date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000)))
    }).on("changeDate",(e) => {
         TimeZoned = new Date(e.date.setTime(e.date.getTime() + (e.date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000)));
        $('#form_datetime').datetimepicker('setDate', TimeZoned);
    });
})
```

Using changeDate event we can set the date to UTC once after user selects the date. But I want the datepicker to be displayed in UTC format, Is there a way to do it? I went through all documentation and tried many ways but no luck. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Try setting `timeZone: ''`. This should default the zone to UTC

Comment: No luck, It still shows the time in local time!